# The field of quotients of the ring of germs of functions.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Let $Y\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ be an affine variety with affine co-ordinate ring $A(Y)=k[x_1\dots, x_n]/I(Y)$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field.

Denote with $\mathcal{O}(Y)$ the ring of all regular functions $f\colon Y\to k$.

Fix an affine variety $Y$ and a point $P\in Y$. Let $U,V\subseteq Y$ be open neighbourhoods of $P$.

For $f\in\mathcal{O}(U)$ and $g\in\mathcal{O}(V)$ define $f \sim g$ if there exists a open neighbourhood $W\subseteq U\cap V$ of $P$ such that $f|_W=g|_W$. Then $\sim$ s an equivalence relation between these the set of all such pairs $(U,f)$. The set $\mathcal{O}_{P,Y}$ (or $\mathcal{O}_P)$ of all equivalence classes is a local ring, called the ring of germs of functions.

For a pair of functions $(U,f)$, $(V,g)$ (as above except we ignore a specific point $P$), define $f\sim'g$ if there exists a open set $W\subseteq U\cap V$ such that $f|_W=g|_W$. Then $\sim'$ is an equivalence relation and the set $K(Y)$ of all equivalence classes is a field.

Denote now with $K(R)$ the quotient field of an integral domain $R$.

I have to prove that in general the following is true:

$$\boxed{K(Y)=K(\mathcal{O}_P)}$$

We consider the restriction map $$\mathcal{O}_{P,Y} \to K(Y)\quad\text{defined as}\quad [f]\mapsto [f]'.$$

I have shown that this map is injective, then results that $$K(\mathcal{O}_{P,Y})\subseteq K(Y).$$

For the opposite inclusion I was suggested to use the following:

> Using the above facts, irreducibility of $Y$ and $$\color{red}{K(Y)=\bigcup_{Q\in Y}K(\mathcal{O}_Q)}$$

> ***Question 1.*** Why is the expression in red true?

show that $$K(\mathcal{O}_Q)=K(Y)\quad\text{for each}\quad Q\in Y.$$

> Could someone suggest me how to proceed? I have no idea how to deal with this inclusion. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you are taking $k$ to be algebraically closed and by 'point' you mean is a 'closed point'.  Is that so?

Comment: @EvansGambit yes, thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 'red' part: Let $f/g\in K(Y).$ Since $g \notin I(Y)$, choose a point $Q\in Y$, such that $g(Q)\neq 0$. Then   $f/g\in K(\mathcal{O}_Q).$

For the rest: Let $Q\in Y$.  Let $f/g\in K(Y).$ If $g\neq 0$ in $\mathcal{O}_Q$, then you are fine as then $f/g\in K(\mathcal{O}_Q).$

If $g=0$ in $\mathcal{O}_Q$, then there is $h\in A(Y)-\mathfrak{m}_Q$ such that $hg=0$ in $A(Y)$. Thus $hg\in I(Y)$. But $h$ and $g$ both are not in $I(Y)$. Contradiction as $I(Y)$ is a prime ideal.

So we are done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One question, what are you using when you say that if $g=0$ in $\mathcal{O}_Q$, then there is $h\in A(Y)-\mathcal{m}_Q$...?

Comment: @Nat. That is what the element in a localization is 0 means. $\mathcal{O}_Q $ is a localization of $A(Y)$ by the multiplicative closed subset $A(Y)-\mathfrak{m}_Q.$

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "...show that $K(O_{Y,Q})=K(Y)$ for each $Q∈Y$."

**Answer:** If $A:=A(Y)$ and if $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A$ is the prime ideal corresponding to $Q$, it follows since $A$ is an integral domain and since localization is "transitive" that there are isomorphisms

$$K(Y)\cong K(A) \cong S^{-1}(A_{\mathfrak{p}}):=K(A_{\mathfrak{p}}):=K(\mathcal{O}_{Y,Q})$$

where $S \subseteq A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is the multiplicative set of non-zero elements.

**Question:** "Thanks. In general, what means that the localization Is transitive?"

**Answer:** If $A$ is a domain, $T:=A-\mathfrak{p}$ with $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal and $S:=A-(0)$, it follows $T \subseteq S \subseteq A$. Let $\tilde{S}:=p(S) \subseteq T^{-1}A$ where $p: A \rightarrow T^{-1}A$ is the canonical map. There are canonical isomorphisms of rings

$$K(A) \cong S^{-1}A \cong \tilde{S}^{-1}(T^{-1}A) \cong K(A_{\mathfrak{p}}).$$

Comment: Thanks. In general, what means that the localization Is transitive?

Comment: @Nat. See Atiyah-Macdonald's Commutative Algebra, Chapter 3, Exercise 3 for the 'transitivity'.

Comment: @Nat. - See the edited post.