# Extension of a morphism of affine varieties $f: X \to Y$ to $\overline{f}: \mathbb{A}^m \to \mathbb{A}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, morphism

I am attempting Exercise 5.5.7 from [this lecture notes](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Ekool0009/AG_notes.pdf). Let $X \subset \mathbb{A}^m$ and $Y \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be closed subsets and a morphism of varieties $f: X \to Y$, extend $f$ to a morphism of varieties $\overline{f}: \mathbb{A}^m \to \mathbb{A}^n$.

My idea is passing from the category of affine varieties to the category of reduced $k$-algebras of finite type. Firstly note that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n}(\mathbb{A}^n)=k[x_1,...,x_n]$ and $\mathcal{O}_Y(Y) \cong k[x_1,...,x_n]/I(Y)$ where $I(Y)$ is the associated ideal of $Y$, similarly $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \cong k[y_1,...,y_m]/I(X)$. My goal is constructing a composition
$$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n}(\mathbb{A}^n) \to \mathcal{O}_Y(Y) \to \mathcal{O}_X(X) \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^m}(\mathbb{A}^m).$$
I intend to take the first arrow as the quotient map to $I(Y)$ and the second arrow as $f^*$. However I have a trouble for the third arrow. I am also thinking about finding a morphism $h: \mathbb{A}^m \to X$, but I don't think we could do this for every closed set in $\mathbb{A}^m$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've found one correct portion: composing with the inclusion $Y\to\Bbb A^n$ gets you half of what you need. The other portion is a little trickier: since a map $X\to\Bbb A^n$ is specified by $n$ regular functions in $k[X]=k[\Bbb A^m]/I(X)$, we can lift our $n$ regular functions defining the map from $k[X]$ to $k[\Bbb A^m]$ and use those to define our map $\overline{f}$.

Comment: Why does composing with the inclusion $Y\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^n$ give you what you need? Where exactly are you composing?

Comment: Also, could you go a bit more in depth in the last part or your argument?

Comment: @kubo just so you know, I left [an answer at your bountied post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4822085/intuition-behind-algebraic-function-field/4837823#4837823). $${}$$ Anyways, the goal here is to take $f:X\to Y$ and get $\overline{f}:\Bbb A^m\to\Bbb A^n$, so you can get part of the way there by taking the composition of $f:X\to Y$ and the natural inclusion $Y\to\Bbb A^n$ to get a map $X\to Y\to\Bbb A^n$: all we have to figure out now is how to lift a map $X\to\Bbb A^n$ to a map $\Bbb A^m\to\Bbb A^n$. But a map $X\to\Bbb A^n$ is determined by $n$ regular functions...

Comment: ... and we know how to lift a regular function on $X$ to $\Bbb A^m$: take any function which maps to it under the surjective map of coordinate algebras $k[\Bbb A^m]\to k[X]$. Since restriction to $X$ is just taking the image along this map, any lift we pick will restrict to the same function on $X$. So we can find a morphism $\Bbb A^m\to\Bbb A^n$ so that the restriction to $X\subset\Bbb A^m$ is our original morphism $X\to\Bbb A^m$, and then this lands in $Y\subset\Bbb A^m$, so we've got our extension.

Comment: This helps you build a continuous morphism between the topological spaces $\mathbb{A}^m$ and $\mathbb{A}^n$. How do you know this respects the sheaf condition?

Comment: @kubo huh? Everything done here is as a morphism of varieties, so it automatically plays nicely with any sheaf conditions you care about. I find it somewhat odd that you are engaging with me here and not on your bountied post. I would have thought that since you bountied it, you would be interested in any answers there.